# Apply Mat-Tootip to Mat-table cell generated using *matRowDef

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Currently I am using some data to create and populate a table dynamically. The number of columns remains consistent but the number of rows changes depending on the data. There is one column in the table that shows a number. I want to add a tool tip that shows on hover, which is extra data related to the data in that row so in the data it's in the same object however, I do not know how to access the individual cells as all of the rows are dynamically generated.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort style="font-size: 4px">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.id}}" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> {{column.value}} </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.id]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Columns:

```
  columnNames = [{
    id: "id",
    value: "ID"

  }, {
    id: "ss",
    value: "SS"
  },
    {
      id: "cd",
      value: "CD"
    },
    {
      id: "type",
      value: "Type"
    }, {
      id: "type2",
      value: "Secondary Type"
    },
    {
      id: "motion",
      value: "Motion"
    },{
      id: "quantity",
      value: "Quantity"
    },{
      id: "in",
      value: "In"
    },{
      id: "error",
      value: "Error Code"
    }];
```

Example Data:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "ss": null,
    "cd": null,
    "type": null,
    "type2": null,
    "motion": null,
    "quantity": null,
    "in": null,
    "error_cd": "603",
    "error_nm": "Description for Error 603"
  },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "ss": null,
    "cd": null,
    "type": null,
    "type2": null,
    "motion": null,
    "quantity": null,
    "in": null,
    "error_cd": "605",
    "error_nm": "Description for Error 605"
  }
```

so when I hover over each cell for the column of error code I want to show a tool tip with the description for the code which is provided in error_nm.

How can I apply a tool-tip to each cell in the error column which will pull the error code description from the same object as that error in dataSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the couple of changes -

1.Change the column name in columnNames array

```
{
    id: "error",
    value: "Error Code"
 }
```

2.Table cell def

```
<mat-cell [matTooltip]="column.id == 'error_cd' ? element['error_nm'] : null" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.id]}} </mat-cell>
```

Here is the working copy https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-file-input-on-radio-sbd37j

Comment: Sorry for delay on the revised Stackblitz, got pulled away. Was about to post update and saw Sunil beat me to it.

Comment: The link you provided seems not working

Answer (score 0):

Add the matTooltip on the mat-cell with conditional data binding, or your could have two mat-cells with *ngIf to render based on if column.id == 'error'.

```
<mat-cell matTooltip={{column.id == 'error' ? element[column.id]['error_nm'] : null}} *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.id]}} </mat-cell>
```

Comment: I don't know if the confusion might be this but the error_nm is not part of the columns it is part of the original data and dataSource

Comment: here is stackblitz of matToolTip only showing on Symbol column with value B https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4ziv8?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: I see, so for error I can define a seperate ng-container that will show the tool tip I'd like for every cell

Comment: I revised my answer as I had some syntax wrong earlier on the original answer, please confirm you are using the current syntax in the answer.

Comment: I saw the syntax issues and fixed it before trying it. However, It was till unresponsive I am trying the ng-container approach now to see if that will make the difference.

Comment: Sounds good. I will work on a stackblitz revision using your data to see if it can stay dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[matTooltip]` attribute helped me to dynamically bind data with each row of the table and display tooltip.

```html
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="tableColumns.<ColumnName>">
  <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header>Column Name</th>
  <td *matCellDef="let row" mat-cell [matTooltip]="row.propertyName">
    {{row.propertyName}}</td>
</ng-container>
```